# Cleaning a lot of bricks after a very long time in storage

Tags: cleaning

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Lego cleaning techniques and tools](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/questions/124/lego-cleaning-techniques-and-tools)

I have a lot of bricks that have been in storage for a few years. They've been stored in a closed big box.

They're now very dirty. It's mainly dust but it's sticky gooey dust. It goes away when i scrub it with water.

What i need is a practical solution to clean all the bricks together. Some kind of solution to put all the bricks in and get them out clean.

Any ideas?