# What disinfectant can I use on used LEGO parts?

Tags: cleaning

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [LEGO cleaning techniques and tools](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/questions/124/lego-cleaning-techniques-and-tools)

I usually purchase LEGO parts at yard sales and the like and would like to disinfect them before using them.  Can I use any spray disinfectant on parts without ruining them?  Should I be wary of any disinfectants that would cause LEGO parts to fade in color?

Comment: Hi Ivan, if you take a look at [my answer](http://bricks.stackexchange.com/a/100/56) to the linked question, you'll see that The LEGO Group recommend using a Mild Bleach for disinfecting your bricks.

Comment: Soaking the parts in a 50/50 mix of warm water and white vinegar works as well - it cleans, removes odors and disinfects without leaving any residue.

Answer (score 2):

In the past I have used dish soap and a basin and just soaked them in hot soapy water for a while. I then learned that MegaBlocks float while LEGO sink.